# What is the standard dictionary for linguistic teminology (English)?

Tags: resource-request

I know the linguistic dictionaries that are used in my language, but I'm looking for a specific term and I need an English one. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the most widely known is David Crystal's *A Dictionary of Linguistics and Phonetics* (1st ed. 1980, 6th ed. 2008, Wiley). There is also *The Cambridge Dictionary of Linguistics*, edited by Keith Brown and Jim Miller (2013, CUP).

For phonetics and phonology in particular, I've also found R. L. Trask's *A Dictionary of Phonetics and Phonology* (1996, Routledge) useful, though unfortunately the author is deceased and some of it is out of date.